# Parsing unicoded file containing non-breaking space character

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse a HTML page in order to find and extract specified items.

As far as I know, the problem is the conflict between BeautifulSoup and Python parser that causes this issue. I'm looking for a specific text in the HTML that'd lead me to and anchor tag to be extracted. 
I don' quite seem to be able to get the problem solved. Here is my code:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
  r = s.get('https://www.rbkc.gov.uk/planning/searches/details.aspx?batch=20&id=PP/11/04187&type=&tab=#tabs-planning-6')
  c = s.cookies.get_dict()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'casefiledocs'})

vals = []
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
  for td in cols:
    if td.get_text().encode('utf-8') == 'Application Form':
      print td
```

Anyone with a solution to this? appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just strip off the whitespace:

```
if td.get_text().strip() == 'Application Form':
    ...
```